# In OpenGL what's the difference between the GL_RED and GL_R color formats?

Tags: opengl, colors, format, glsl

When loading in a single channel 8 byte texture my renderer works only with `GL_RED`. It took me a while to figure out `GL_R` doesn't work for me. I couldn't get an explanation of what it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The is no `GL_R` color format, hence one cannot describe its differences to `GL_RED`.

The `GL_R` enum is totally invalid for any use as a color format, and does not mean "red". This enum is part of the four enums `GL_S`, `GL_T`, `GL_R`, `GL_Q`, which are the symbolic names for the four-dimensional texture coordinates in the GL. Note that this enum was used to specify the old fixed-function texture coordinate generation (see for example [`glTexGen()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexGen.xml)), which is deprecated nowadays. As a result, the `GL_R` enum *does not even exist* in modern OpenGL at all (so you find it in the legacy `gl.h`, but for example not in [`glcorearb.h`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glcorearb.h)).

Comment: OK, that was confusing. Thank you.